# yet another java generic question

Tags: java, generics

Again I'm facing issues with generics, I thought I now know how to do this. To illustrate I created this simple example.

Given this interface

```
public interface Converter<A, B> {
    B encode( A a);
}
```

why does the following error:

```
void onRequest(ArrayList<String> a,Converter <? extends List<String>,String> conv) {
    conv.encode(a);
}
```

I expected that, with this notation, conv.encode would accept any param that extends List

any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you mean Eng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
void onRequest(ArrayList<String> a,Converter <? super List<String>,String> conv) {
    conv.encode(a);
}
```

You want to call encode with an ArrayList, therefore ArrayList has to be a subclass of the furst type parameter of Converter. Therefore this first type parameter has to be a **super** class of ArrayList. By making it be super of List this is automatically guaranteed.

Comment: PECS in action :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: The famous, yet underestimated `super` keyword... :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Converter <? extends List<String>,String>` allows allows all `Converter` types with a first generic parameter that is a subtype of `List`, for example `Converter<LinkedList, String>`. If we pretend that you code could type check, in you example, that would allow you to call onRequest as:

```
void onRequest(ArrayList<String> a,Converter <? extends List<String>,String> conv) {
    conv.encode(a);
}

void callsOnRequest() {
    onRequest(new ArrayList<String>(), new Converter<LinkedList<String>,String>); 
}
```

This is not what you mean to allow.

If you replace `extends` by `super` you essentially say to the compiler that the the Converter's second parameter must be **no more specific than** `List` and thus any list (for example your `ArrayList`) will be assignable to the a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

"? extends String" does NOT mean "any subtype of List<String>", BUT "an unknown subtype of List<String>".

Method onRequest accepts a Converter object which is parametrized with some unknown List<String> subtype. Therefore, it is saying clients that it might be passed a Converter<ArrayList<String>, String> as well as a Converter<LinkedList<String>, String> -- which is not what you want.

I think there is no need to use wildcards at all, in this example. If you want onRequest to be able to pass an ArrayList, then a Converter<List<String>, String> is enough.

You may also use a Converter<? super List<String>, String>, but this will allow clients to pass a Converter<Object, String> as well as a Converter<Collection<String>, String> etc.